# The recent inequality contest problem

Tags: inequality, polynomials, contest-math

I have a recent olympiad problem about inequality.

> Polynomial $P(x)=x^3+x^2+x+a$ is given for $a>0$. Let $r$ be any real root of $P(x)$. Prove that, $$-\frac{4a}{3}\leq r<\frac{1-4a}{4a}$$ Can $r=\dfrac{1-4a}{4a}$ be a root?

While the second question might seem easy, it was actually difficult. Because $x=\dfrac{1-4a}{4a}$ gives $64a^4-64a^3+32a^2-8a+1=0$. I know that $64a^4-64a^3+32a^2-8a+1=$ is a perfect square . Hence $(8a^2-4a+1)^2=0$ gives $8a^2-4a+1=0$. But the discriminant is negative. So my answer to the second question is "no". Let me be clear, I found the perfect square using Wolfram Alpha. How else can we figure the perfect square not using softwares ? Time in the contest is very limited and I need your strong suggestions here. I got stuck on the first question the most. The fact that $a$ is a positive number forces $r$ to be negative. Hence $r^2\le\dfrac{16a^2}{9}$ and $r^3\ge-\dfrac{64a^3}{27}$, so nothing comes from here. Because the inequality signs are in different directions. The harder part is to prove that $r<\dfrac{1-4a}{4a}$, because it's hard to talk about the sign of $\dfrac{1-4a}{4a}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to notice that $r<0$.

**For the first part of the first question:**

$$\begin{align}
-\frac{4a}{3}\leq r &\iff -\frac{3}{4}r \le a\\
&\iff -\frac{3}{4}r \le -r-r^2-r^3 \\
&\iff r\left(r^2+r+\frac{1}{4} \right) \le 0 \\
&\iff r\left(r+\frac{1}{2} \right)^2 \le 0 \hspace{1cm} \text{true}
\end{align}$$

**For the second part:**
$$
r<\frac{1-4a}{4a} \iff \frac{1}{a} >4(1+r) \tag{1}
$$
if $r\le -1$ then obviously, $(1)$ holds true. Suppose that $-1 < r <0$, then
$$\begin{align}
(1) &\iff a < \frac{1}{4(1+r)} \\
&\iff \frac{1}{4(1+r)}+r+r^2+r^3 >0 \tag{2}
\end{align}$$
We study the LHS of $(2)$, we have
$$\begin{align}
LHS &:= \frac{1}{4(1+r)}+r+r^2+r^3\\
&=\frac{1}{4(1+r)}+r\frac{1-r^3}{1-r}  >\frac{1}{4(1+r)} +\frac{r}{1+r}=\frac{(2r+1)^2-r}{4(1+r)(1-r)} >0
\end{align}$$
By consequence, $(2)$ holds true.

Q.E.D

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $x^3 + x^2 + x + a$ is strictly increasing, and along with $a > 0$, this implies that there is exactly one real solution, so $\frac{1-4a}{4a}$ cannot be a root, since we are told that $r$ is a root, and $\frac{1-4a}{4a} > r$ is given.

Comment: @user1215800 $P''(x) = 6x + 2$, and $P'(x) = 0$ has no solutions.

Comment: @user1215800 I don't have a proof; you didn't ask for that in the original question.  I assume that you can reach a contradiction by assuming it to not be the case, but I don't care to find out.
If you don't believe why $x^3 + x^2 + x + a$ is increasing for any real $x$ and don't accept formal proofs, then I suggest examining the polynomial.  It should be clear that $P(x+b) > P(x)$ for any $b > 0$, since each term will be pairwise larger.

Comment: That's given in the problem, by you.  However, as @NN2 said, it is essentially a tautology.

Comment: Because you (are supposed to) prove an inequality that states $r < \frac{1-4a}{4a}$.

Comment: No, I am assuming it to be true, otherwise the problem is faulty and has no answer.

Comment: Your question was, and I quote:
"While the second question might seem easy, it was actually difficult."
So I gave you a way to instantly answer the second part of the question.

Comment: "...and along with $a > 0$, this implies that there is exactly one real solution, so $\frac{1-4a}{4a}$ cannot be a root" .Sorry but why ? Why $\frac{1-4a}{4a}$ cannot be a root ?

Comment: Because there is one real root, and this root is strictly smaller than that quantity (as given in part 1 of the question).